# Почему криво строится график кусочной функции

Tags: python

Пытаюсь построить треугольную функцию принадлежности кусочной функцией, но почему-то выводит не корректно на plot (картинка во вложении)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def s_similar(x, a, b, c):
  if x <= a:
    return 0
  elif x > a and x <= b:
    return (x - a)/(b - a) 
  elif x > b and x <= c:
    return -(x - b)/(c - b) + 1
  else:
    return 0
  

x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
g = np.vectorize(s_similar)
y = g(x, 20, 50, 80)


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому что Питон у вас версии 2.X. И деление целых чисел у вас целочисленное. А надо чтобы было вещественное. `x = np.arange(0, 100, 1)` -> `x = np.arange(0., 100., 1.)`.

Comment: Станислав, у меня в 3.9 тоже самое и хотя выводы у вас правильные, но решение - нет, оно не сработает. Надо использовать `g = np.vectorize(s_similar, otypes=[np.float])` - показать питону, что вычислять надо не целочисленно

Answer (score 1):

потому что у вас идет вычисление в целых числах и все эти деления дают результат < 1, т.е 0

используйте вот такой код:

```
g = np.vectorize(s_similar, otypes=[np.float])
```

и все будет в порядке

вылезает предупреждение на счет `float` (`DeprecationWarning: 'np.float' is a deprecated alias for the builtin 'float'.`), поэтому используйте лучше такой код:

```
g = np.vectorize(s_similar, otypes=[np.float64])
```

он не выдает никаких предупреждений

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хм, забавно, что превращение `x` в `np.float` не помогает, хотя по описанию `vectorize` вроде бы должно помогать.